# How to make an ACI for users that are `roleOccupant` in an `organizationalRole`?

Tags: migration, access-control-list, 389-ds

In OpenLDAP I had an access rule using users that are `roleOccupant`s in a specific `organizationalRole` like this (the example is just a fragment):

```
olcAccess: to * by group/organizationalRole/roleOccupant.exact="cn=Manager,dc=roles,dc=example,dc=org" write
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to convert this to an ACI for 389-DS.
What I tried without success was:

```
aci: (targetattr = "*")(version 3.0; acl "Manager test"; allow (all)(userdn="ldap:///cn=Manager,dc=roles,dc=example,dc=org??one?(roleOccupant=*)");)
```

Tracing the ACI evaluation I see that 389-DS is searching in `dc=people,dc=example,dc=org` for `cn=Manager,dc=roles,dc=example,dc=org` as a direct child (`one`).

But I must admit that I'm overwhelmed by the complexity of the ACIs as described in [1.10. Defining ACI bind rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/12/html/managing_access_control/assembly_managing-access-control-instructions_managing-access-control#assembly_defining-aci-bind-rules_assembly_managing-access-control-instructions).
Originally I had thought, I could use `roledn=`, but with the existing structure no roles are listed by `dsidm`; it seems it only works for "Netscape Roles" (`nsRoleDefinition`, etc.).

So is it possible to use by existing role structure for access control in 389-DS?